# Can I transfer through Vancouver airport without Canada visa? Air Canada and Turkish Citizen

Tags: canada, transit-visas, us-residents, turkish-citizens, air-canada

I'm a Turkish citizen living in USA (temporary resident on a H-1B) and I just bought a flight that transfers through Vancouver Airport.

The  itinerary is as follows:

```
Air Canada 8090 -> Seattle, USA to Vancouver, Canada
    10:57am arrival and 12:00pm departure    -     1 hour 3 minutes layover
Air Canada 63 -> Vancouver, Canada to Seoul, South Korea

Air Canada 64 -> Seoul to Vancouver
    10:35am arrival and 1:45pm departure     -     3 hour 10 minutes layover
Air Canada 8095 -> Vancouver to Seattle
```

I have my legal travelling required documents ready for both South Korea and USA. However I do not possess a Canadian Tourist Visa or any sort of transit visa.

Is there a connection area in Vancouver airport that would allow me to take these flights?

Vancouver airport told me that I need a visa, CBSA told me that I need a visa but many people online say that I don't. I only have a carry-on and will not have any luggage checked in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

You will need a Transit visa. Its free to apply.

https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/transit/apply.html

Comment: Yeah, I cancelled my flight after finding out. Thanks.